# git push heroku stopped working?

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

this was working till about an hour ago - has anyone had this happen to them or can anyone suggest a solution?

Simply, when i type  `git push heroku` the cursor just sits there, blinking, but not actually doing anything. (the push up to github works fine).

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to monitor the [Heroku status page](https://status.heroku.com/)

For instance, right now, it says:

> **Elevated Error Rates**
>
> Issue: We are investigating elevated error rates with git push, and api operations. Some running apps may be affected by errors with dyno unidling.
>
> Jan 10, 2012 – 18:53 UTC – 31 minutes ago